# developer studio 3.8.0 not working on eclipse 4.5.1

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio

I am having problems using developer studio 3.8.0 on the eclipse 4.5.1 (mars)

the installation of the developer studio on eclipses 4.5.1. went well(see the attached screenshot install history ; 
[image]

yet after the installation, the "developer studio" tool button disappeared from the top tool bar of the eclipse; (see the attached screenshot);

[image]

also the "wso2" selection disappeared from the selection items under the "new" button (see attached screenshot)
[image]

does anyone have idea?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WSO2 Developer Studio 3.8.0 is recommended to install on "[Eclipse Luna SR2](https://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/lunasr2)". Use Eclipse for Java EE Developers. Installing Developer Studio 3.8.0 on Eclipse Mars is not supported.

You can also download [Eclipse Java EE Luna SR2 with Developer Studio 3.8.0](http://wso2.com/products/developer-studio/).

Answer (score 0):

Install [Enterprise Integration Tooling](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI600/Installing+Enterprise+Integrator+Tooling). It is newest version included eclipse 4.5.2 (Mars.2)