# WSO2 Developer Studio - Eclipse Support

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio

I can't locate a roadmap that depicts when the Developer Studio will support the later version of Eclipse than Luna. I have a need to use Mars (4.5.1) but according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34251233/developer-studio-3-8-0-not-working-on-eclipse-4-5-1), 4.5.1 is not supported by DS 3.8.0.

Can someone point me in the right direction for information about when this will be supported? Is there a workaround?

Also, there appears to be a issue on the eclipse marketplace documentation that states that Mars is a supported platform for the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 Developer Studio Kernel 4.1.0 is on Eclipse Mars (4.5)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.